# Repeated roots i characteristic equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we have the Euler-Cauchy differential equation:
$$x^ny^{(n)}+a_1x^{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+...+a_{n-1}xy'+a_ny=0$$
and a particular solution:
$$y_1=x^p$$ Where $p$ satisfies the characteristic equation:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\frac{p!}{(p-n+k)!}a_k\right)=0$$
and we get a root for the upper polynomial that repeats $n$ times:
$$p_1=p_2=p_3=...=p_n$$
Now is there a way to derive a general algorithm that gives us the rest of the solutions:
$$
y_2=x^p\text{ln}(x) $$ $$
y_3=x^p\text{ln}^2(x) $$
$$. $$
$$. $$
$$. $$
$$ y_n=x^p\text{ln}^{n-1}(x)
$$
I've searched online but I find answers only for specific order of ODEs but not a general algorithm. Also tried to derive it myself but couldn't do it past the reduction of the order by one using the substitution:
$$y_2=y_1u(x)$$

Comment: This is something called a generalized eigenvalue. You can look up the term generalized eigenvectors in ODEs for more details, but in short, if we have an eigenvector $$Av = \lambda v$$ which is also an eigenvector of $$f(A)v = f(\lambda)v$$ then generalized eigenvectors of order $n$ have eigenvalues of the form $$f^{(n)}(\lambda)$$ In your case, you found $x^p$ as a repeated root solution. That means the generalized eigenvalues were $$f^{(m)}(p) = x^p\log^mx$$ The number of orders corresponds to the size of the Jordan block, which is the multiplicity of the root.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Can you elaborate more? Isn't that a method for solving a system of ODEs? How do I use it in my case?